# Flutter toggle button

Tags: flutter, user-interface, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

[image]

How to make this type of toggle button in flutter

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Switch](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Switch-class.html) widget to achieve that.

The simplest implementation is as follows:

```
Switch(
  value: _switchState,
  onChanged: (value) => setState(() => _switchState = value),
),
```

Note that this Widget itself doesn't hold any state, so you have to keep track of whether it is active or not and switch the state in the `onChanged` callback.